# How Can I decode from the given Authentication

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want Decode  of the given token.My Issue is Can't find  jwt-decode.
Now That time I am Using, this npm install jwt-decode,

After Installation finished, this module call in this where we are using that Component like this

```
var jwtDecode = require('jwt-decode');

after that i am calling in 
componentDidMount(){
    this.getToken()
    } 


  getToken(){

                var token ='eyJ0eXAiO.../// jwt token'  
                var decoded = jwt_decode(token);
                alert(":"+decoded);


  }
```

Please Suggest any one , this method or any method. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assigning the jwt-decode function to a variable named `jwtDecode`, but your `getToken` function appears to be calling `jwt_decode`. If you change that to `jwtDecode`, and pass in a real token (rather than the example string), it should then work.